# Generating UML Class Diagram from Smalltalk code

Tags: uml, smalltalk, visualworks

Currently, I am working with a Smalltalk based application server, using Visual Works. I am looking for a way to generate a UML Class Diagram from the code. I have looked up for many tools but nothing seems to work or be useful.

Answer (score 5):

VisualWorks distribution contains a tool named ADvance which allows a round-trip UML class diagraming, that is, you can re-engineer class diagrams from your code, edit this class diagram then generate code from changes. You can also edit code directly from a diagram.  Quite a handy simple tool and it is pity it not much known.

To load ADvance, open Parcel Manager and among Suggestions click Developer tools. ADvance is a first parcel listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Moose is a software analysis and visualization tool for Smalltalk. It offers many different views on Smalltalk code and you can explore your system visually. No strict UML visualizations though.

You find more here, http://moose.unibe.ch

http://morlhon.net/blog/images/codecrawler.png